# Execute an action for all component of a rule in bison

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I have the following rule in my bison file :

```
affectation: VAR '=' expr ';'
    | VAR PLUSEQ expr ';'
    | VAR MINUSEQ expr ';'
    ;
```

I would like the parser to display the variable name and its content every time an affectation is done. For that, I use the action `{printf("%s:%s\n",$1, $3);}`. However, as there are 3 forms of affectation, is there a way to apply this action to all the components without writting :

```
affectation: VAR '=' expr ';'
      {printf("%s:%s\n",$1, $3);} 
    | VAR PLUSEQ expr ';'
      {printf("%s:%s\n",$1, $3);}
    | VAR MINUSEQ expr ';'
      {printf("%s:%s\n",$1, $3);}
    ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the answer is no. In most use cases, the three productions would have different semantics, so it would be normal for their to be three different actions, although they might share code. (As always, refactoring the shared code can reduce the need for duplication.)

If the three rules were really semantically identical, you could collect the different operators into a prefix rule:

```
aff_pfx: VAR '=' | VAR PLUSEQ | VAR MINUSEQ
affectation: aff_pfx expr ';' { handle($1, $2); }
```

That relies on the default action copying `$$ = $1` in all the productions for `aff_pfx`, so it is not fully general. Also, it completely erases any distinction between the three syntaxes, which seems unlikely to be correct.

If you are just trying to produce a trace of the parse,take a look at bison's built-in debugging features.

Comment: You could also use `affectation: VAR eqop expr ';'`, with `eqop : '=' | PLUSEQ | MINUSEQ`, which might be a little easier to understand.  The problem with both trasformations is if you want to use precedence on the operators to resolve ambiguities, it will no longer work -- you need to duplicated rules to make precedence work.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I'm not sure exactly how this grammar might need precedence on these particular operators, but opening the grammar up a bit to allow cascading assignment and more interesting lvalues still seems to work with `aff_pfx` and precedence declarations. It wouldn't work with the `eqop` formulation, which is why I didn't use it in the first place.